# Can't set style with TargetType Shape

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to set the [`Shape.Stroke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.stroke(v=vs.110).aspx) property for several shape types using a style in WPF.

```
<Style.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Polyline}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
  </Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
  </Style>
  ...
</Style.Resources>
```

It does not seem possible to just set the style for the base class `Shape`.

```
<Style.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Shape}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White"/>
  </Style>
</Style.Resources>
```

Is there no better way than the first option I listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When WPF searches for an implicit `Style`, it looks for a resource whose key matches the `DefaultStyleKey` of the element to be styled.  The convention in WPF is that every control `T` overrides the `DefaultStyleKey` to be `typeof(T)`.  WPF will **not** attempt to fall back to the base type's style key if a match is not found.

`Ellipse`, for example, has an implied<sup>[1]</sup> default style key of `typeof(Ellipse)`, so WPF will only attempt to resolve an implicit style with that key; a resource keyed on `typeof(Shape)` will not be applied.

If you want to use implicit styles, you will need to define an implicit `Style` per concrete type.  However, those styles may inherit setters and triggers from a common base `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="x" TargetType="{x:Type Shape}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Ellipse" BasedOn="{StaticResource x}" />
<Style TargetType="Path" BasedOn="{StaticResource x}" />
<Style TargetType="Polyline" BasedOn="{StaticResource x}" />
```

Note that while *implicit* styles for base types will not be applied automatically, they are still compatible, and they can be applied *explicitly*:

```
<Style x:Key="StrokedShape" TargetType="{x:Type Shape}">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
</Style>

<!-- ... -->

<Ellipse Style="{StaticResource StrokedShape}" />
```

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> Some WPF elements do not override `DefaultStyleKey`.  `Shape` and its subclasses are among them.  In such cases, WPF *assumes* the default convention.</sub>

Comment: Definitely an improvement, thanks! I seem to recall I knew this, ... must have forgotten. :)